# Sql Error UserID, RoleId invalid Column Name on Login Asp.Net MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I have a web app using entity framework 6. Identity 2. MVC 4.
I will try to explain the things I was working on leading up to this error:

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'UserId'.
Invalid column name 'UserId'.
Invalid column name 'RoleId'.

Source Error: //In the Account Controller.cs

```
  {
      AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
   }
```

First, I added a relationship between AspNetUser table and a custom table "CustomerTicketInfo" in the Entity Designer. I Updated the Db from the Model and ran this auto generated Sql:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Entity Designer DDL Script for SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2012 and Azure
-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Date Created: 08/13/2014 10:15:49
-- Generated from EDMX file: C:\Projects\DevTeam\Logistics Mobile MVC\LMSMobile\LMSMobile\Models\LogisticsManagementModel.edmx
-- --------------------------------------------------

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
GO
USE [LTGLogisticsManagement];
GO
IF SCHEMA_ID(N'dbo') IS NULL EXECUTE(N'CREATE SCHEMA [dbo]');
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Dropping existing FOREIGN KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo_AspNetUserClaims_dbo_AspNetUsers_User_Id]', 'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo_AspNetUserClaims_dbo_AspNetUsers_User_Id];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo_AspNetUserLogins_dbo_AspNetUsers_UserId]', 'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo_AspNetUserLogins_dbo_AspNetUsers_UserId];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRole]', 'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRole];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUser]', 'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUser];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_AspNetRoles_AspNetRoles]', 'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetRoles_AspNetRoles];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_AspNetUsers_AspNetUsers]', 'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUsers_AspNetUsers];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_AspNetUserCustomerTicketInfo]', 'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerTicketInfoes] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserCustomerTicketInfo];
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Dropping existing tables
-- --------------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[CustomerTicketInfoes]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[CustomerTicketInfoes];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetRoles]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUsers]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles];
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all tables
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- Creating table 'CustomerTicketInfoes'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerTicketInfoes] (
    [Oid] uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL,
    [Commodity] nvarchar(100)  NULL,
    [ContractLocale] nvarchar(100)  NULL,
    [ArrivalNumber] nvarchar(100)  NULL,
    [PickUpNumber] nvarchar(100)  NULL,
    [OriginSignature] nvarchar(100)  NULL,
    [DestinationSignature] nvarchar(100)  NULL,
    [OptimisticLockField] int  NULL,
    [GCRecord] int  NULL,
    [Trucker] nvarchar(50)  NULL,
    [AspNetUserId] varchar(50)  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'AspNetRoles'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles] (
    [Id] varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'AspNetUserClaims'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] (
    [Id] varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
    [ClaimType] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [ClaimValue] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [User_Id] varchar(50)  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'AspNetUserLogins'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins] (
    [UserId] varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
    [LoginProvider] nvarchar(128)  NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey] nvarchar(128)  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'AspNetUsers'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id] varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
    [UserName] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [PasswordHash] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [Discriminator] nvarchar(128)  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'AspNetUserRoles'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] (
    [AspNetRoles_Id] varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
    [AspNetUsers_Id] varchar(50)  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all PRIMARY KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- Creating primary key on [Oid] in table 'CustomerTicketInfoes'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerTicketInfoes]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomerTicketInfoes]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Oid] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [Id] in table 'AspNetRoles'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetRoles]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [Id] in table 'AspNetUserClaims'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUserClaims]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [UserId], [LoginProvider], [ProviderKey] in table 'AspNetUserLogins'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUserLogins]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId], [LoginProvider], [ProviderKey] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [Id] in table 'AspNetUsers'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUsers]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [AspNetRoles_Id], [AspNetUsers_Id] in table 'AspNetUserRoles'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUserRoles]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AspNetRoles_Id], [AspNetUsers_Id] ASC);
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all FOREIGN KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- Creating foreign key on [User_Id] in table 'AspNetUserClaims'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo_AspNetUserClaims_dbo_AspNetUsers_User_Id]
    FOREIGN KEY ([User_Id])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_dbo_AspNetUserClaims_dbo_AspNetUsers_User_Id'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_dbo_AspNetUserClaims_dbo_AspNetUsers_User_Id]
ON [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]
    ([User_Id]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [UserId] in table 'AspNetUserLogins'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo_AspNetUserLogins_dbo_AspNetUsers_UserId]
    FOREIGN KEY ([UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [AspNetRoles_Id] in table 'AspNetUserRoles'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRole]
    FOREIGN KEY ([AspNetRoles_Id])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetRoles]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [AspNetUsers_Id] in table 'AspNetUserRoles'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUser]
    FOREIGN KEY ([AspNetUsers_Id])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUser'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUser]
ON [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]
    ([AspNetUsers_Id]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Id] in table 'AspNetRoles'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetRoles_AspNetRoles]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Id])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetRoles]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Id] in table 'AspNetUsers'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUsers_AspNetUsers]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Id])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [AspNetUserId] in table 'CustomerTicketInfoes'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerTicketInfoes]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserCustomerTicketInfo]
    FOREIGN KEY ([AspNetUserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_AspNetUserCustomerTicketInfo'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_AspNetUserCustomerTicketInfo]
ON [dbo].[CustomerTicketInfoes]
    ([AspNetUserId]);
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Script has ended
-- --------------------------------------------------
```

After running that Sql it created a new table called CustomerTicketInfoes which has the AspNetUser relationship that I wanted (but it's no longer using my originally created table).

I then Enabled Migration Using PM. And I updated Model From database since there was a new table created.

I'm not sure if any of this has anything to do with the error. But this is what I was working on when I got the error above. Simply trying to login to the web app. with a registered Username + Pass. I also tried a different browser thinking it had something to do with cookies. Still fails.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: did you run **PM> Update-Database**?. Or check if the values are going to a different db (they could be looking at the default db instead that's made)

Answer (score 10):

1. Rename the Fields of Table `AspNetUserRoles`

   ```
   a. From `AspNetRole_Id` to `RoleId`

   b. From `AspNetUser_Id` to `UserId`
   ```
2. Update Model From Database
3. Try Login it will work fine now.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! Any idea why it defaults to the former?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it must be using the wrong tables, no? Perhaps in your db context class, applicationdbcontext in the default version, so just explicitly set the table names, something like

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); // This needs to go before the other rules!

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("AspnetUser");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("AspnetRoles");
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().ToTable("etc");
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>().ToTable("etc");
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>().ToTable("etc");
}
```